# converge uniformly and converge in probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

What is the relationship between converge uniformly and converge in probability?

**For this question:**

$\{f_{n}\}_{n=1,2,...}$ be a sequence of real valued functions that converge uniformly to $f$ on an open set $S$, containing $x$, and $f$ is continuous at $x$. Show that if $\{X_n\}_{n=1,2,...}$ is a sequence of random variables taking values in $S$ such that $X_{n} \overset{p}{\to} X$, then $f_{n}(X_{n}) \overset{p}{\to}f(X)$.

**My proof is like this:**

Since $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1,2,...}$ converge uniformly to $f$, it means that:

$\forall \epsilon > 0,  \exists N_{\epsilon} , \ni \forall n > N_{\epsilon}  , |f_{n}(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$.

So, now fix $\epsilon$, for $n > N_{\epsilon}$, $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ holds for all $x \in S$. This means that $Pr[|f_{n}(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon]=1$ holds for sufficiently large $n$ ($n > N_{\epsilon}$).

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} Pr[|f_{n}(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon]=1$.

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} Pr[|f_{n}(x)-f(x)| > \epsilon]=0$ for arbitrary $\epsilon$.

So, $f_{n}(X_{n}) \overset{p}{\to}f(X)$.

Is there any problem to do this prove? I feel it very strange.

Comment: You have to distinguish between random variables and point $x$. A notation like $P(|f_n(x)-f(x)| <\epsilon)$ does not involve any random variable and this probability is always $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1):

This result is false.You are only given continuity of $f$ at $x$ and that is not enough. For a counterexample take $f_n=f$ for all $n$, $X_n=y+\frac  1 n, X=y$. Then the statement $f_n(X_n) \to f(X)$ in probability is equivalent to continuity of $f$ at $y$. So if $f$ is not continuous at $y$ we get a contradiction.